# Get data from Wiki to CSV file / database

Tags: csv, web-scraping, data-mining

What is the easiest way to get some data from wikipedia? I would like to get it as CSV file.

Basically the data what I would like to get is just list of names. For example, all the British actors names from this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_actors_and_actresses
(All from A-Z and names would be enough).

Is this possible? Also this would be done only once so no need for caching or anything like. Just simple get data perform. But I have no clue how to do it really.

PHP, JS, Jquery, JSON would be nice. No java or anything like that!

Comment: Can I ask what is wrong with this, why the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at DBPedia and Google Refine. IIRC Google Refine had an example extracting and cleaning data from Wikipedia ([see video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LovigIDl634&feature=player_embedded)). And DBPedia is a database copy of Wikipedia already.